# Visual Studio Code C# Extension not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, msbuild, omnisharp

Windows 10 Pro x64

I have been trying for days to fix this issue, downloaded multiple different versions of the .NET SDK, but I still get this error from the C# extension:
"The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path."

I have gone to that help page, and it says to type where.exe into a cmd prompt window, which I did, and received a result, then referred back to the help page, and it said, "There are no known reasons why PATH wouldn't be propagated to the VS Code process."

Here are my OmniSharp output logs:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 11/8/2021, 4:43:45 PM
    Target: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\bEan.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 15972

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to 'c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild
            MSBuildToolsPath = c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\bEan.sln'.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\UnityEngine.TestRunner.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.Timeline.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\UnityEngine.UI.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\UnityEditor.TestRunner.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\UnityEditor.UI.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.Services.Core.Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Found project that doesn't exist on disk: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan' on host 11172.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'UnityEditor.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0.402" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'UnityEditor.UI.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2068,5): Error: The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\eleph\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): Error: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0.402" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\eleph\Unity Projects\bEan\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

For reference, this is a C# file from a Unity project, but regular C# files don't work either. Please help, I currently am programming without IntelliSense and without correct syntax highlighting, and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Error messages are text, and can be copy/pasted or typed directly into your question. Images should be used only when an issue cannot be demonstrated in any other way, which is not the case with a simple textual error message.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, I've now fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to VS, VSCode doesn't really have much Unity support compared to VS.